# create custom control without gui

Tags: c#, controls

How can I create a custom control that has no gui? Like Timer, OpenFileDialog etc. They're placing not on the form but on the bottom panel of designer window
Can you recommend some useful books about it?

Comment: Just inherit the `Component` class.

Comment: Thanks. It's clear now.
And how can I add new Properties to controls on form when my component added on this form? Like RowSpan and ColumnSpan which appear if control is on the TableLayoutPanel?